# MvcSiteMapProvider FindSiteMapNode returning parent node instead of current node

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

When I have:

```
var node = SiteMap.Provider.FindSiteMapNode(HttpContext.Current);
```

and the page I'm on is excluded by site roles, the `FindSiteMapNode` is returning the closest visible parent of the node I'm on.  I expected it to return `null`.

How can I test to see if the page being accessed is visible in the SiteMap?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I test to see if the page being accessed is visible in the SiteMap?

You can use the `SiteMap` HTML helper to see all of the currently visible nodes in the SiteMap.

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap()
```

The line

```
var node = SiteMap.Provider.FindSiteMapNode(HttpContext.Current);
```

will only work with MvcSiteMapProvider v3.x or before. This is accessing the ASP.NET SiteMap provider model, which v4.x is no longer based upon. As pointed out in the [documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Upgrading-from-v3-to-v4#updating-systemwebsitemap-code-references), the proper syntax for v4.x is

```
var node = MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.FindSiteMapNodeFromCurrentContext();
```

> MvcSiteMapProvider FindSiteMapNode returning parent node instead of current node

As for this issue, you clearly have more than one node configured to match the route (whatever it is). The [first match always wins](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position).

Note that if you are using v3.x or before it used to attempt to do "partial matches" which could be the cause of this issue. It was also set up to always return the root node instead of null when no match was found. Both of these issues have been fixed in later versions of v4.x.

Comment: This sounds good... I'll have to determine which version I have!